# Solr query on Europe character (Beklædning)

Tags: encoding, solr

in solr query search,
a search

```
q=*%3A*&fq=grand_cat_str%3ABeklædning
```

Solr will read the fq as:`<str name="fq">grand_cat_str:BeklÃ¦dning</str>`

and return no result. Doing wild search for Bekl*dning would return correct result.

[edit]
I added

```
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" >
 <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

but got a error:

```
<org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: FieldType: StrField (string) does not support specifying an analyzer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is indeed an escape problem.
using org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(String)
is able to make string readble.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how Solr handles characters that are not in the first 127 ASCII character set. The best recommendation is add the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) analyzer to your field `grand_cat_str` in your schema.

Please reference [Specifying an Analyzer in the Schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Specifying_an_Analyzer_in_the_schema) if you need guidance on adding a analyzer.

Comment: adding the analyzer gave me error, please see original question for specific error with better formating

Comment: You will need to change the class to `class="solr.TextField"` on the fieldType to be allowed to specify an analyzer on the field.

Answer (score 0):

If most documents in his corpus are in that same language (Dannish?) then it is very possible that applying ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory is a bad option, depends on how the users are expected to enter their queries.

Have you tried just encoding the query??

```
q=*%3A*&fq=grand_cat_str%3ABekl%C3%A6dning
```

should work just fine